# python dictionary insert to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I am trying to take the data from a dictionary and insert it into a mysql database. I have the following piece of code.

```html
import pymysql

connect = pymysql.Connect(
    host='localhost',
    port=3306,
    user='root',
    passwd='my729501s',
    db='major',
    charset='utf8'
)
data = {'video_title': 'hanzi', 'id': 1, 'video_url': 'www.bad.com', 'image_url': 'www.baidu.com', 'subject_title': 'nothong'}
cursor = connect.cursor()
table = 'video_title'
cols = data.keys()
vals = data.values()
sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES(%s)" % (table, ",".join(cols), ",".join(vals))

cursor.execute(sql)

connect.commit()
connect.close()
cursor.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EViL.jpg)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/untitled1/python4.py", line 18, in <module>
    sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES(%s)" % (table, ",".join(cols), ",".join(vals))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: The image have the description about the error

Comment: I hope that's not your real password...

Comment: The password must be correct!

Comment: Sure, but you don't need to post it publicly

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there is an interger in your list `vals`. So you need to cast it to string. Modify your code as below.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES(%s)" % (table, ",".join(cols), ",".join(str(x) for x in vals))
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/untitled1/python4.py", line 18, in <module>
    cols = data.keys()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: data = {'video_title': 'hanzi', 'id': 1, 'video_url': 'www.bad.com', 'image_url': 'www.baidu.com', 'subject_title': 'nothong'}
data = json.dumps(data)

Comment: Do the modification to your original code. Do not do the json.dump() I asked you to do earlier.

Comment: only change the sql = .... line only. What I have pasted in this answer.

Comment: Thank you  for your help,but the code can't run ,too!

Comment: pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'nothong' in 'field list'")

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'nothong' in 'field list'")
Exception ignored in: <bound method Cursor.__del__ of <pymysql.cursors.Cursor object at 0x0000016C57C1E0F0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists